# Skrollr.js out of sync with viewport

Tags: jquery, html, parallax, skrollr

I'm using Skrollr right now, but somehow my animations are being triggered a lot later or earlier than they should, and it changes every time I load the webpage.
For example:

```
<DIV data-bottom-top="opacity: 0;" data-center-center="opacity: 1"> This is some text </DIV>
```

This ideally should show up as my text being transparent at the bottom of my screen (the top of the element is at the bottom of the viewport), then as it moves to the exact centre of my screen, the opacity should be fully at 1. When I loaded it on Chrome, Opacity becomes one about 200 px above the center of the screen. When I first loaded it on Firefox, it was the same. When I loaded it again on Firefox, opacity was 1 about 100 px BELOW the center of the screen.
What's going on?

Thank you

Comment: Are there by any chance images on the page? Make sure to init skrollr after they have been loaded (they affect layout/height of the page).

Comment: Yes, Skrollr is set to load right before </body>

Comment: "Yes, Skrollr is set to load right before </body>", which is before the images have loaded.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reminder. Reviewed the documentation again and missed that part the first time through =)